# Is there a way to write a Ruby loop that runs one iteration for a maximum set amount of time?

Tags: ruby, loops, timer

I'm looking to create a Ruby (MRI 1.9.3) loop that runs at most for a certain amount of time, and once that time is up it goes to the next iteration of the loop.

For example, this is what I'm hoping to achieve:

```
timer = Timer.new
while foo
  timer.after 5 do # The loop on foo only gets to run for 5 seconds
    next
  end

  # Do some work here
end
```

So far, I've found tarcieri's gem called Timers (https://github.com/tarcieri/timers) which is what I'm trying to emulate in the code above, but my implementation doesn't give the behavior I expect, which is for the loop to go to the next iteration after 5 seconds if my work takes longer than that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
require 'timeout'
timeout_in_seconds = 5
while foo
  begin
    Timeout.timeout(timeout_in_seconds) do
      # Do some work here
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
    next
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been awhile since I brushed off my Ruby skills, but I believe you can do this with the timeout library.

```
require 'timeout'

while foo
    Timeout.timeout(5) do
        work()
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
time = 60
time_start = Time.now
begin      
      time_running = Time.now - time_start
      #You_code_goes_here
end until (time_running.to_i >= time)
```

That loop will happen until the `time_running` var is equal or greater than "60".